# Regex to match up to 2 full words and the next word containing the character

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've developed the following regular expression to use in a search field.
The goal is to use it to match up to 2 words, then the full word with the character(s) and everything after:

```
/^
    .*?                 # match anything before, as few times as possible
    (
        (?: 
            [^\s]+\s*   # anything followed by whitespace
        ){1,2}          # match once or twice
        \s*?            # match whitespaces that may be left behind, just in case
        [^\s]*?         # match the beginning of the word, if exists
    )?  
    (foo|bar)           # search term(s)
    ([^\s]*\s*.*)       # whatever is after, with whitespace, if it is the end of the word
$/xi
```

The problem is that it isn't always matching correctly.
A few examples, when searching for "a":

```
Fantastic drinks and amazing cakes

Expected match:
$1 = F
$2 = a
$3 = ntastic drinks and amazing cakes

Result:
$1 = Fantastic drinks (space)
$2 = a
$3 = nd amazing cakes

-----------------------------------------

Drinks and party!

Expected match:
$1 = Drinks (space)
$2 = a
$3 = nd party!

Result:
$1 = Drinks and p
$2 = a
$3 = rty!

------------------------------------------

Drinks will be served at the caffetary in 5 minutes

Expected match:
$1 = be served (space)
$2 = a
$3 = t the caffetary in 5 minutes

Result (matches correctly):
$1 = be served (space)
$2 = a
$3 = t the caffetary in 5 minutes
```

You can experiment with it on https://regex101.com/r/cI7gZ3/1 with unit tests included.

The way that this doesn't work is strange, beyound what I can describe. But, my guess, is that this is prefering matches that have 1-2 words *before* the search term.

What do you think that may be wrong here? What do you think that is causing these issues?

Comment: What about `Ffffantastic`? How should be captured parts?

Comment: If what is in the 2nd capturing group (I refer to as `search term`) is the "a" used in my examples, it should store `Ffff` in the 1st group and `ntastic` on the 3rd.

Comment: I see you accepted the answer but a question: do you have letters and spaces only or other characters can be in your input string too?

Comment: @revo Anything counts. It won't have newlines, but will have all sorts of whitespace and symbols. Mostly limited to ISO-8859-15/ANSI/CP-1252/Windows-1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using lazy versions of `\S+` and `{1,2}` in

```
(?: 
    \S+?\s* # anything followed by whitespace
){1,2}?
```

and remove the `[^\s]*?         # match the beginning of the word, if exists` part.

See the [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE1vS2/2)

```
^
  .*? # match anything before, as few times as possible
  (
    (?: 
      \S*?\s* # anything followed by whitespace
    ){1,2}?
    \s* # just in case there's whitespace
  )?
  (a) # search term(s)
  (\S*\s*.*) # whatever is after, without whitespace if it is the end of the word
$
```

Comment: It fails for `Fantastic drinks and amazing cakes`, matching `Fant` in the first group instead of `F`.

Comment: Actually, I got a problem. Is is mismatching `testing this can be tested`. It should be `testing this(space)` in the first group and is matching `this c`. But it is so much closer than what I want. Adding the `[^\s]*?` back seems to fix it.

Comment: Ok, that means another test case to be added to the question. I am in the sandpit now, so can't help for the time being.

Comment: Don't worry. The `[^\s]*?` bit should stay. This way, it seems to work properly. I'm testing it with real data and real searches and it works perfectly with my change. I will mark again as accepted, edit it when you can.